# SQL Server CE wildcards

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, wildcard

My database has a `products` table. This contains a column called `layers`. That column contains data in the form of `0102`, where `01` is the closet and `02` is the layer in that closet.

I need to query my database for closets as well (not only layers). How do I use wildcards, so that I can query for all products in - for example - closet `01`, `02` and `03`?

This is what I have now, but it isn't working:

```
SELECT Artikelnummer, Omschrijving, Legger, Voorraad 
FROM Artikels 
WHERE Legger LIKE 01* OR  Legger LIKE 02* OR  Legger LIKE 03*  
ORDER BY Artikelnummer
```

(Sorry for the dutch names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Server T-SQL uses the `%` as the wildcard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/069b0htd%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for "any characters (and `_` for one character, any character - equivalent to `?` in Windows/DOS), any numbre thereof" - and you also need to put your string literals into single quotes - so use:

```
SELECT Artikelnummer, Omschrijving, Legger, Voorraad 
FROM Artikels 
WHERE Legger LIKE '01%' OR  Legger LIKE '02%' OR  Legger LIKE '03%'
ORDER BY Artikelnummer
```